# код выдает неверный ответ

Tags: python

решала задачу:

> Подсчитайте количество способов представить натуральное число n
> в виде суммы двух различных натуральных чисел, каждое из которых не превышает k
> и первое число меньше второго.

```
примеры
Ввод
3 5
Вывод
1

Ввод
2 4
Вывод
0

5 6
Вывод
2
```

Написала по ней код, но тестирующая система пишет, что он выдает неверный ответ на четвертом тесте. Мой код:

```
n, k=map(int, input().split()) 
ans=0
for i in range(1, n//2+1):
    if i<n-i and n-i<=k:
        ans+=1 
print(ans)
```

Конечно, на приведенных выше тестах все работает хорошо, но я не знаю, что еще исправить.

Comment: Ну например у тебя не корректно отрабатывает при равных значениях `n` и `k`, подставь значения 5 5, исправляется это если записать `<= k` во втором условии

Comment: поправила код в вопросе, но некоторые тесты все равно не проходит

Comment: а если подставить 6 6?)))

Comment: нужно в первом ифе сделать так же, тогда выводит 2, то есть все нормально, но все же что-то еще не исправлено...

Comment: Думаю что проблема в производительности. Набирать миллиарды по единичкам не разумно.

Comment: но ведь это не имеет отношения к неправильному ответу

Comment: Вы ошибку в вопросе не показываете. А на слово я вам, извините, не верю.

Comment: Попробуйте это: `print(max(0, (n + 1) // 2 - max(1, n - k)))`. Если пройдёт, я напишу ответ.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, цитирую проверяющую систему: "Неправильный ответ на тесте 4"

Comment: Такая догадка: вы читаете числа *n* и *k* в обратном порядке. Во всех трёх тестах в вопросе, если порядок перепутан, результат не меняется.

Comment: вы правы, но теперь код работает слишком долго

Comment: @Настя Я же дал код, который за одну операцию считает ответ

Comment: все исправила, спасибо вам, дело было в неправильном считывании входных данных!!!

Answer (score 2):

Число 2 не логично составлять из чисел меньших 4-х (хотя и возможно)

Ваш вариант можно было бы записать короче с использованием дополнительно переменной:

```
def test(n, k):
    counter=0
    delta = 1 if n%2 == 0 else 0
    for i in range(n//2-delta):
        if i<n-i and n-i<=k:
            counter+=1
    print(counter)
```

Теперь с условием сказанного в начале перепишем Ваш вариант так, он дает те же ответы:

```
def test2(k, n):
    counter = 0  
    for i in range(n//2+1):
        a = i
        b = n - i
        if (a < b  and b <= k):            
            counter +=1
    print(counter)
```

> ```
> test(3, 5) # 2,3  = 1 
> test(2, 4) # 2,2  = 0 (числа не могут быть равными)
> test(5, 6) # 1,5;2,5 = 2
> ```

Comment: к сожалению, ваш код также неправильный, ошибки на тех же самых тестах

Comment: @Настя, можете скинуть где Вы проверяете код?

Comment: проверяю в Codeforces

Comment: @Настя случайно нет ссылки на задачу?

Comment: нет возможности отправить(

Answer (score 1):

Простая функция, дающая верные результаты:

```
def tst(n, k):
    counter = 0
    for lo in range(1, (n+1)//2):
        hi = n - lo
        if hi <= k:
            counter += 1
    return counter
```

Оптимизированная:

```
def sum_distinct(n, k):
    return max(0, min(n - 1, k) - (n-(n-1)//2) + 1)
```

Откуда что взялось:
меньшее слагаемое находится в диапазоне `1..lo=(n-1)//2`
большее - в диапазоне `n-lo..n-1`
применив к верхней границе ограничение k, получаем количество вариантов сумм

Comment: нет, некоторые ответы все же неверны...

Comment: Известно, какие? А то на наборе случайных примеров я ошибок не вижу.

Comment: Тесты неизвестны, причем я тоже не вижу в вашем коде ошибок