# Найти минимальное число, произведение цифр которого равно N

Tags: python

я писала код по задаче

> Дано натуральное число N
> Найдите минимальное число большее 10, произведение цифр которого в точности равно N

Но на некоторых тестах (которые, к сожалению, неизвестны) моя программа работает слишком долго.

```
n=int(input()) 
ans="No solution"
if n==0:
    print(10)
elif n<10:
    print(int("1"+str(n)))
else:
    for i in range(int("9"*n)):
        i=str(i) 
        a=1 
        for j in range(len(i)):
            a*=int(i[j])
        if n==a:
            ans=i 
            break
    print(ans)
```

Я не знаю, что не так... Помогите пожалуйста разобраться!

Comment: А зачем два вопроса сразу задавать? =)

Comment: этот и [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1519683/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82)

Comment: два кода одновременно не работают...

Comment: @PeterKolosov а что не так? Вопросы разные.

Comment: @Настя исправьте заголовки, чтобы было понятно, о чем вопрос. Тут во всех вопросах неправильный ответ или код не работает или проблема с задачей

Comment: Задача, кстати, не всегда решаемая. Например, для простых чисел решения нет.

Comment: может ли быть проблема в том что минимальное числе большее 10 не включает 10, то есть для n = 0 минимальное это 20?

Comment: @FBXR Замечание правильное по коду, но автора беспокоит другая проблема кода

Comment: @Эникейщик по идее даже если число не простое, но при этом является произведением простого числа на какое-то другое число то решения нет, с тем условием, что это простое число не однозначное, а двузначное, трехзначное и тд

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделал небольшую функцию, которая решает эту задачу (если вводимое число кратно какому-либо простому числу (кроме 1,2,3,5,7)-функция выведет это простое число вместо ответа):

```
n = int(input())
def min_mult_num(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 10
    elif n < 10:
        return int('1' + str(n))
    else:
        n_mute = n
        list_help = []
        final_num = []
        for i in range(2,10):
            list_help.append(i)
        list_help = list_help[::-1]
        while len(str(n_mute)) > 1:
            for i in list_help:
                if n_mute%i == 0:
                    final_num.append(i)
                    n_mute = int(n_mute / i)
                    break
            else:
                return (f"Мы столкнулись с простым числом {n_mute}")
        final_num.append(n_mute)
        final_num = final_num[::-1]
        f = int(''.join((str(i) for i in final_num)))
        return f

min_mult_num(n)
```

если надо что то объяснить по логике функции, то напишите в комментах к этому ответу, постараюсь объяснить

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю небольшую рационализацию внутреннего цикла - досрочное завершение, если ответ явно не получится уже и крутить цикл дальше бесполезно:

```
        for j in range(len(i)):
            a*=int(i[j])
            if a == 0 or a > n:
                break
```

Хотя нужно проверять, даст ли это экономию. В принципе, должно дать, потому что операции сравнения чисел очень дешёвые, а вот парсинг строки в число - очень дорогая операция. Умножение не сильно дорогое.

Но вообще явно задачу нужно решать в обратную сторону - с разложения на множители. Так должно быть гораздо быстрее.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем решении есть несколько недочётов.

1. Условие `if n == 0:` не нужно. *n* - натуральное, нулём быть не может.
2. Очень долго ждать ответа если решения нет. Минимальное *n* без ответа - *11*. Вы запускаете цикл из *99_999_999_999* итераций. 100 миллиардов - много. Правило большого пальца: современный компьютер делает порядка миллиарда элементарных операций в секунду. 100 секунд можно было бы подождать, но у нас и операции не элементарные. Быстрая прикидка показывает что миллион итераций ваша программа делает за три секунды. А требуется в 100_000 раз больше.
3. Это не ваш недочёт, а странность в условии задачи: почему ответ должен быть больше десяти? Не понятно. Я пока опущу это условие - буду искать минимальное число с нужным произведением цифр.

Перебор кандидатов напрашивается, но не всегда простейшее решение - лучшее. Разберем примеры для *n = 18*. Если задача имеет решение, то цифры решения должны делить *18*. Подходят *2*, *3*, *6*, *9*. Из них можно скомбинировать такие ответы: *18 = 2 * 3 * 3 = 2 * 9 = 3 * 6*. С точностью до порядка множителей других комбинаций нет.

Разберёмся с порядком: *2 * 9 = 9 * 2*. Из равенства следуют два решения: *29* и *92*. Нам нужно меньшее: *29*. Вывод: цифры в числе должны не убывать. Если они в каком-то месте убывают, пару цифр можно поменять местами и получить меньшее число с тем же произведением.

Второе наблюдение: чем меньше цифр, тем меньше число: *2 * 9 = 2 * 3 * 3*. *29 < 233*.

Тогда алгоритм такой: делим *n* на *9* пока делится и выписываем девятки справа налево в разряды числа. Затем переходим к *8* - выписываем восьмёрки пока делится. Продолжаем пока не дойдём до *2*. Когда все двойки выписаны, проверяем что *n = 1*. Если нет, в *n* есть множители которые не могут быть цифрами - ответа нет.

Этот алгоритм строит самое короткое число (второе наблюдение) и цифры в нём не убывают (первое наблюдение).

Если в ответе получилось число из одной цифры, добавляем к нему спереди единицу, чтобы соответствовать "странному" условию из задачи:

```
n = int(input()) 
answer = []
for d in range(9, 1, -1):
    while n % d == 0:
        n //= d
        answer.append(str(d))
if n > 1: # n не является произведением чисел от 2 до 9
    print('No solution')
else:
    if len(answer) == 0: # это бывает если n = 1
        answer.append('1')
    if len(answer) == 1: # это бывает если n < 10
        answer.append('1')
    print(''.join(reversed(answer)))
```

> ```
> $ echo 1 | python digits.py
> 11
>
> $ echo 2 | python digits.py
> 12
>
> $ echo 9 | python digits.py
> 19
>
> $ echo 10 | python digits.py
> 25
>
> $ echo 11 | python digits.py
> No solution
>
> $ echo 50 | python digits.py
> 255
>
> $ echo 1000000000000 | python digits.py
> 5555555555558888
> ```