# Программа работает слишком долго

Tags: python

Всем привет, решала такую задачу:

Похожие массивы

Назовём два массива похожими, если они состоят из одних и тех же элементов
(без учёта кратности). По двум данным массивам выясните, похожие они или нет.

Входные данные

В первой строке содержится число N(1≤N≤100000)
— размер первого массива. Во второй строке идут N
целых чисел, не превосходящих по модулю 109
, — элементы массива. Далее аналогично задаётся второй массив.

Выходные данные

Программа должна вывести слово YES, если массивы похожи, и слово NO в противном случае.

Примеры

```
Ввод 
3
1 7 9
4
9 7 7 1
```

Вывод

```
YES
```

Ввод

```
4
1 2 3 4
3
5 1 3
```

Вывод

```
NO
```

Я написала по ней программу

```
n=int(input()) 
l1=list(map(int, input().split())) 
m=int(input())
l2=list(map(int, input().split())) 
ans="YES"
if len(l1)>len(l2):
    a=l1
    b=l2
else:
    a=l2 
    b=l1
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] not in b:
        ans="NO" 
        break
print(ans)
```

Но она работает слишком долго, на 3-ем тесте не укладывается в лимит по времени. Помогите пожалуйста!!!

Comment: l2 - замените list на set. Сложность алгоритма из квадратичной превратится практически в линейную.

Comment: @Настя Постарайтесь называть вопросы так, чтобы заголовок отражал суть, а то у вас всё "слишком долго" или "не работает". [Вот, например, вам нормально подправили](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1519685/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Иcпользуйте не `list`, а `set`

При применении `list` тоже можно побыстрее, если отсортировать, но со множествами лучше